# Specifying properties on unity injected objects

Tags: constructor, unity-container, code-injection

I'm having an interesting problem with Unity, and any help is appreciated.

I want to inject an array of objects in a constructor, and I want to associate each object with a code during that injection.
Note that there can be more than one object with the same code, so I can't have a Dictionary.

I'm basically trying to inject small objects into a containing object, and then the containing object will use the code to access these objects when necessary.

I would be fine with using a KeyValuePair; I would also be find if I had to construct a composite object (like below).
What I would rather not do is to seperately register all of the combinations of Code/Object elements before-hand.  I don't mind registering each of the injected objects.

I'd like to do something like this (I know it's not valid):

```
<register type="IMyObject" mapTo="MySmallObject1" name="SmallObject1" />
<register type="IMyObject" mapTo="MySmallObject2" name="SmallObject2" />
<register type="IMyObject" mapTo="MySmallObject3" name="SmallObject3" />


<register type="ContainingObject1" name="Name1">
  <constructor>
    <param name="objects">
      <array>
        <value>
          <!-- This could resolve to a KeyValuePair or a composite object -->
          <property name="Code" value = "01" />
          <property name="Operation" >
            <dependency name="SmallObject1" />
          </property>
        </value>
        <value>
          <property name="Code" value = "02" />
          <property name="Operation" >
            <dependency name="SmallObject2" />
          </property>
        </value>
      </array>
    </param>
  </constructor>
</register>

<register type="ContainingObject2" name="Name2">
  <constructor>
    <param name="objects">
      <array>
        <value>
          <property name="Code" value = "01" />
          <property name="Operation" >
            <dependency name="SmallObject3" />
          </property>
        </value>
      </array>
    </param>
  </constructor>
</register>
```

So in the first contained object, I'm injecting two pairs: code 01 with SmallObject1, and code 02 with SmallObject2.
For the second, there's only one pair: code 01 with SmallObject3.
I know that I could write a custom type converter that could take a string of the form "01,SmallObject1" and convert it to a string and the object by resolving the type name in code. 
I was hoping to avoid that, if possible, and control all of this in the config.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Phil